# how to make discord bot to get user eth address and store them in database?

Tags: discord, ethers.js

i need to make a very simple discord bot to verify and show eth address and show which user it belongs too. Need to  associate a verified eth address for each member of my server. It'll be stored in a database. I can check which eth address a certain user has with a command.

Any idea how to implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to implement eth address verification, you can simply make a command that accepts one parameter as an eth address and store that in the database and another command that fetches it back upon request

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).